# Mocking vue-router's useRoute() in Jest tests in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and Vue-Router for my app, and I'm having trouble when creating unit tests with Jest on components that use `useRoute()`, such as the following:

```html
<template>
    <div :class="{ 'grey-background': !isHomeView }" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default defineComponent({
    setup: () => {
        const isHomeView = computed(() => {
            return useRoute().name === 'Home';
        });

        return {
            isHomeView,
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

The `computed` property is using `useRoute()`, and it is used in the template.
When I make a Jest test on this component, an error is thrown saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

I tried mocking `useRoute` like so :
`jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({ useRoute: jest.fn() }));` and then on the `beforeEach`: `useRoute.mockReturnValueOnce({ name: 'Home' });`, but it doesn't work.

I'm not talking about Vue 2 in which the router works differently but Vue 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is your factory function (i.e., in `{ useRoute: jest.fn() }`) has no mock return specified (i.e., it returns `undefined`), so `useRoute().name` is trying to access `name` from `undefined`, which generates the error you mentioned.

You could either update the mock factory to return an object with a `name` property:

```js
jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRoute: jest.fn(() => ({ name: 'Home' }))
}))
```

...or mock them inside the tests instead of using the factory:

```js
jest.mock('vue-router')

describe('MyFoo.vue', () => {

  it('should have grey background for Home view', () => {
    require('vue-router').useRoute.mockReturnValueOnce({ name: 'Home' })
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyFoo)
    expect(wrapper.html()).not.toContain('grey-background')
  })

  it('should not have grey background for non-Home view', () => {
    require('vue-router').useRoute.mockReturnValueOnce({ name: 'About' })
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyFoo)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('grey-background')
  })
})
```