# Vue 3 Vitest - Jest route mock

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vitest

I'm trying to mock vue-router's route which I am using in one of my components like **route.path** . I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218291/mocking-vue-routers-useroute-in-jest-tests-in-vue-3) implementation and the outcome looks like:

```
vi.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRoute: vi.fn(() => ({ path: '/signIn' }))
}))
```

But after running tests I'am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
```

Comment: Where the error come from?

Comment: When testing, the file roure.path is used

Answer (score 0):

useRoute returns a `Ref` to the route object. You'd need to change it to something like this:

```js
vi.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRoute: vi.fn(() => ({ value: { path: '/signIn' } }))
}))
```